# should i deal with ID's or with models

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

i am using sequelize and when i want to set products for an order (M2M Relation)
i must put all the product object not only the id
EX:

```
Order.setProducts([1,2,3]) // dont work
Order.setProducts([{name: "1",price: 1},{name: "2",price: 2}]) // work
```

so i was wondering is that good for performance
and should i always deal with whole object or i should deal only with the ID's and after getting the ID's i do this ..

```
Product.findById(id)
```

for each productid i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetProducts is a function add to an sequelize instance because of your associations in the model. So calling it with the ids dont work, because your are writing the ids directly in your product table. If you want to push only the ids. Which at the the end is a better structure, you need an addiontal table, where your store id of the order and ids of the products.

In your case, in your posted question above, you are adding, the product details each time you create an order.